# What error has the value of one in regards to the file_save_upload in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, files

I called `file_save_upload` and then `form_get_errors`. `form_get_errors` returned 1.

What is this error? I tried googling for this error, but I guess the words I used to search for it weren't good enough.

Comment: whats the error message

Comment: Do you know how to get the error message? I tried drupal_get_messages(), but it returned an empty array and a number one.

Comment: I just found out I could go to the reports page, but I can't seem to find any pertinent information.

Comment: I found the answer, but I am not sure how to proceed. This question explains it further: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/160795/how-do-i-do-a-file-upload-with-other-form-data-in-drupal-6