# How do I do a file upload with other form data in Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, forms

I have this in my form function:

```
$form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data');
... other form fields
$form['form']['form_file'] =  array (
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#name' => 'form_file',
    '#attributes' => array ('class' => 'textarea_crmform'),
 );
```

and when I call file_save_upload in my submit function, I am doing this:

```
if ($file = file_save_upload('form_file'))
```

But it never gets into the above if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there's an error. Have you looked at your watchdog log? Is the temporary directory setup and writable by the web server?

Comment: The temporary directory is set up to be writeable. Also, I made a small form on the side as shown here: https://www.computerminds.co.uk/file-uploads-drupal-6-part-1 and it worked fine. I don't have any errors listed from the module I am making. The difference between my form and the example is that I have a 2D array and the example as a 1D array. I am wondering if this is the issue and how I would deal with using a 2D array.

Comment: What about checking the watchdog log ... anything there? Also, try naming the first dimension something else than `form` and remove the `#name` parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the name from form, but this didn't seem to fix it. However, Removing the #name parameter did it. Any idea as to why that is?

Comment: Not sure - the input name usually comes from the array key, so maybe since they were the same value, something kooky happened. Glad it works now! Back away slowly... ;)